# Formatting GetChildItem output in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm a almost total beginner using powershell, but very interested in learning because I think it's awesome what you can do with it. I'm not looking to be spoonfed a script, but rather get directions on how I could create something like I need. I've googled somewhat but I feel like my lack of understanding in powershell is preventing me from accomplishing what I need.

I've got a bunch of scientists that are sequencing DNA. Once they run the sample a program creates two files per sample. One of them is marked R and the other F. So the filename for each is DNA-SAMPLE-1-R and DNA-SAMPLE-1-F.

They usually run a bunch of samples so there are maybe 20-30 files in the folder once they need to add them to a text file which needs to be formatted a certain way. The complete txt file should look like this :

There should be one TAB space between file names, and the next sample begins underneath the last.

DNA-1-A DNA-1-B

DNA-2-A DNA-2-B

DNA-3-A DNA-3-B

I've managed to make powershell output these files in a txt file in the folder. But I'm having trouble with getting the format right. What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a .ps1 they can run preferrably with minimum editing.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$object = (gci -Path C:\Test -Exclude prufa.txt)
$object.Name -join '  ' | Out-File C:\Test\prufa.txt
```

This outputs the contents of the C:\Test folder into a txt file without the prufa.txt which powershell creates. And this is what i'm getting:

`DNA-1-A  DNA-1-B  DNA-2-A  DNA-2-B  DNA-3-A  DNA-3-B`

Now I only need to pair DNA-1-A with 1-B, and then have 2-A and 2-B start underneath etc. so it looks like what I mentioned above. And is there a way for me to have the script maybe just take the newest subfolder created and list the items from that ? So that I dont have to have them edit the script every time they intend to run it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet to group your files by shared name prefix (the start of the name up to, but excluding the last `-` segment in the name), which then allows you to join
the members of each group with a tab (`` `t ``) as the separator to form a single string:

```bash
# Get the most recently created subdir.
Get-ChildItem -Directory |          
  Sort-Object CreationTimeUtc | 
  Select-Object -Last 1 |  
  # Get all files in that subdir., excluding file prufa.txt
  Get-ChildItem -File -Exclude prufa.txt |
  # Group by shared name prefix (the name with the last "-" segment removed)
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '-[^-]+$' } | 
  # Join each group's members with a tab char.
  ForEach-Object { $_.Group.Name -join "`t" } # | Out-File ... omitted
```

As an aside:

- `Get-ChildItem -File -Exclude prufa.txt` works to exclude file `prufa.txt`, because the pipeline input implicitly binds to the `-LiteralPath` parameter; if the input directory were to be provided via `-Path`, a *bug*, present up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.6, would make the combination of `-File` with `-Exclude` produce *no output* - see [GitHub issue #20191](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20191).